# Set Express Checkout method returning an failure in the ack

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I want to do the express checkout process in the paypal for the customers without redirecting the browser. I have written the code like

```
        string sAPIUser = apiuser;
        string sAPIPassword = password;
        string sAPISignature = "signature";
        string sAPIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";           
        string sAppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";

        StringBuilder sRequest = new StringBuilder();

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = ("&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout");
        postData += ("&VERSION=63.0");
        postData += ("&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00");
        postData += ("&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD");
        postData += ("&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale");
        postData += ("CANCELURL=http://www.google.com");
        postData += ("RETURNURL=http://www.google.com");
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
```

// Prepare web request...

```
   HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sAPIEndpoint);
   myRequest.Method = "POST";
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", sAPIUser);
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", sAPIPassword);
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE", sAPISignature);
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.3.0");
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");
   myRequest.Headers.Add("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", sAppID);
   myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
   // Send the request, read the response
   Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
   newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   newStream.Close();
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
   Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   Encoding encoding2 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding2);
   string theResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
   theResponse = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(theResponse);
```

But i am getting the failure message in the `theResponse` variable. What error i am doing. The error is like

```
    TIMESTAMP=2013%2d03%2d05T05%3a55%3a38Z&CORRELATIONID=5c10035aca937&ACK=Failure&VERSION=63%2e0&BUILD=5331358&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication%2fAuthorization%20Failed&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

How can i rectify this.

Comment: Kinda a bad idea to leave your api credentials in your question.  You may want to remove those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the credentials you are using are for your sandbox account and not your live account.  Your code looks like it is pointing to the sandbox, so you would need to use your sandbox credentials.  Also, if this is not all of your code, make sure you are not passing across a variable called "SUBJECT" and populating it with an email address.

Comment: i am not using any subject variable

Comment: The 10002 error is only caused for a limited number of reasons.  You are either using the wrong credentials for the endpoint you are pointing, the endpoint is wrong, or you are passing over a subject variable and you don't have permission to execute an API call on the account that you are passing over in the subject.  Try re-copying your API credentials over from your test account, and into your code.

Comment: yah i have found the error i have missed the `&` symbol for cancelurl and returnurl